# Single Application Instance in android

Tags: android

After pressing home button during my running application and when I am going to launch application again from icon it launches another instance of application. How can I prevent from this. I want application should resume its previous state instead of launching another main activity. Please help.

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>  this is my manifest file please help

Answer (score 1):

You should save all the relevant state in your activity's `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore the saved values in `onCreate()` from `savedInstanceState` (if it's not null).